What is the TL Parameter in Google Account Signup URL and How is it Generated?
I'm seeking information about the TL parameter found in Google account signup URLs. For example, in the following URL:
https://accounts.google.com/signup/v2/idvbyphone?TL=AC3PFD6-WtS06OH8_-wAQ24DcqJe9gw_JOF9NDPTfvSF07xgEpI3BrgayC29nRp3&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ddm=0&dsh=S-922261782%3A1717270103078506&flowEntry=SignUp&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&hl=en&service=mail&theme=glif
TL=AC3PFD6-WtS06OH8_-wAQ24DcqJe9gw_JOF9NDPTfvSF07xgEpI3BrgayC29nRp3

What does the TL parameter stand for and what information does it contain?
How is this parameter generated?
Why does altering its value invalidate the session?
